# QNX pidin command display only last 21 characters of thread name

Tags: multithreading, qnx

In QNX, `pidin` command display only last 21 characters of thread names. Is there any way that I can print complete name of the threads?

For example, below command

```
$ pidin threads | grep myapp
```

output is:

```
643167 ./myapp              rvice::WorkerThread1 SEM         d5458760
643167 ./myapp              rvice::WorkerThread2 SEM         d54589b8
```

Where as my threads complete names are `CMyService::WorkerThread1` and `CMyService::WorkerThread2`

I am expecting output to be as below,

```
643167 ./myapp              CMyService::WorkerThread1 SEM         d5458760
643167 ./myapp              CMyService::WorkerThread2 SEM         d54589b8
```

Answer (score 0):

The max length supported is 100 characters.
So that means you can print more than 21. Try the below command -

```
pidin –F "%b %50h" –p <pid>
```

Comment: Sorry for not motioning QNX version. I am using version 6.5.0. Above command gave error `pidin: –F invalid shorthand`

Comment: Not sure why it is not working for you as this flag is supported from QNX 6.3.2 version. 
Could you please share the snapshot of your shell where you are running this command? Maybe something is wrong with the way you used the command?

Answer (score 0):

or just do "pidin | less" and press enter to scroll down